# How to read a PoS tagged csv file using R?

Tags: r, csv, part-of-speech

I have a CSV file of POS tagged data ( using Stanford NLP POS Tagger).

Example:

1. Worst_JJS support_NN ever_RB NOT_RB BUY_VB just_RB broken_JJ phone_NN  Support_NN doesnt_NN care_NN stay_VB away_RB products_NNS
2. Worst_JJS services_NNS purchase_NN product_NN

How do I read the POS tagged CSV file in R? I am trying to use readTagged() function in 'tm' package but it shows the following error:

```
> output= read.csv(file = "Test.csv", header = TRUE)
> vs <- VectorSource(output)
> ele <- getElem(stepNext(vs))
> doc <- readTagged()(ele, language = "en", id = "id1")
```

Error in textConnection(elem$content) : invalid 'text' argument

I have tried the read.tagged() in koRpus package but it is not recognizing the tags of Stanford NLP POS Tagger.

My next question is, Is it possible to stem the text retaining the POS tags in R?